# Can I make the default date in column 1 to be equal to Column 2?

Tags: list

I need the default value in column 1 to match column 2 unless overridden. 
I cant work out how to have the default value the same as another column. which is not Todays date.

Comment: You are SPS or SPO, do you need this value filled in the NewForm immediately or it can be filled later?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

1. Create column 1 as calculated column and set return type as Date Time

[image]

Or

2. Create simple Sharepoint design workflow, that updates value of column 2 into column one at the time of item creation or modification.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ic9Je9AlAf4

Comment: you cannot edit calculated values.

Comment: Question doesn't ask about editing column1 value, it only talking about setting its value in automated way

Comment: read again the first sentences, "overriden" i think calculated will always be refreshed. He probably need to edit form or do some WF. I asked for more information.

Comment: thanks, thats why we have another solution suggested using sharepoint designer :)